# Query Comparing Multiple Columns based on different data in each column in Access SQL

Tags: sql

Good Morning/Afternoon,

I will attempt to phrase this correctly. I have a table with multiple fields that I am trying to create certain output results on in a query.

QueryA:

| Property | Bldg | Unit | Flag1 | Date1 | Cost1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | Y | 1/1/2022 | $1,000 |
| 2 | A | 1 | Y | 1/1/2022 | $2,000 |
| 2 | A | 1 | N | 1/1/2022 | $1,000 |
| 3 | A | 1 | N | 1/1/2022 | $1,000 |
| 3 | A | 1 | N | 1/1/2022 | $1,000 |
| 4 | A | 1 | Y | 5/5/2022 | $1,000 |
| 4 | A | 1 | N | 1/1/2022 | $1,000 |
| 5 | A | 1 | Y | 1/1/2022 | $1,000 |
| 5 | A | 1 | N | 1/1/2022 | $1,000 |

I would like to create the desired output below:

| Property | Bldg | Unit | Flag1 | Date1 | Cost1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | Y | 1/1/2022 | $1,000 |
| 2 | A | 1 | Y | 1/1/2022 | $2,000 |
| 3 | A | 1 | N | 1/1/2022 | $1,000 |
| 4 | A | 1 | Y | 5/5/2022 | $1,000 |
| 5 | A | 1 | Y | 1/1/2022 | $1,000 |

Essentially if there is a Y flag then the table should pull that row. Barring that a single N field should be selected. I've tried Max(Flag1) but both Y and N rows are still pulled whenever another value in a different column is different.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access is way more limited than I could ever imagine hehe... Check if you can make this work, I used the strategy to create tables to save the data in a way Access accepts the queries.

First create this table:

```
SELECT Property,
       Bldg,
       Unit,
       Max(Flag1) AS Flag_1       
INTO BaseTable
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Property,
         Bldg,
         Unit
```

Then create this other table:

```
SELECT BaseTable.Property,
       BaseTable.Bldg,
       BaseTable.Unit,
       BaseTable.Flag_1,
       MAX(MyTable.Date1) AS Date_1
INTO BaseTableWithDate
FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN BaseTable ON BaseTable.Property = MyTable.Property
                  AND BaseTable.Bldg = MyTable.Bldg
                  AND BaseTable.Unit = MyTable.Unit
                  AND BaseTable.Flag_1 = MyTable.Flag1             
GROUP BY BaseTable.Property,
         BaseTable.Bldg,
         BaseTable.Unit,
         BaseTable.Flag_1
```

And finally you can run the query that returns what you need:

```
SELECT BaseTableWithDate.Property,
       BaseTableWithDate.Bldg,
       BaseTableWithDate.Unit,
       BaseTableWithDate.Flag_1,
       BaseTableWithDate.Date_1,
       MAX(MyTable.Cost1)
FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN BaseTableWithDate ON BaseTableWithDate.Property = MyTable.Property
                      AND BaseTableWithDate.Bldg = MyTable.Bldg
                      AND BaseTableWithDate.Unit = MyTable.Unit
                      AND BaseTableWithDate.Flag_1 = MyTable.Flag1
                      AND BaseTableWithDate.Date_1 = MyTable.Date1                     
GROUP BY BaseTableWithDate.Property,
         BaseTableWithDate.Bldg,
         BaseTableWithDate.Unit,
         BaseTableWithDate.Flag_1,
         BaseTableWithDate.Date_1
```

Comment: Paulo, first thank you for looking into this and responding! I have tested the formula above, using the same table name, query, and data listed here and I'm receiving a "Cannot aggregate function in Where clause (Property=MyTable.Property And Bldg=MyTable.Bldg AND Unit=MyTable.Unit=MyTable.Unit And Flag1=Max(myTable.Flag1)). 
  I tried switching the where clause over to a HAVING clause but had no luck with that either unfortunately.

Comment: Hi! This time I tested in Access, I was able to run the queries at least. Hope you can make this work.

Comment: Thanks again for following up on this Paulo, this typifies my experience with access as well, but I'm glad a solution could be found.